# How can I target router-outlet from a child component?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a left nav component that is imported into my main AppComponent. What I'm trying to implement is the ability to click a link in the left nav, and have it load a DataComponent in the router-outlet of the parent AppComponent.

My parent AppComponent looks like this:

```
import { LeftNavComponent } from 'app/left-nav/left-nav.component';
import { DataComponent } from 'app/data/data.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'main',
  template: '<left-nav></left-nav><router-outlet></router-outlet>',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, LeftNavComponent]  
})
@RouteConfig([
  {path:'/data', name: 'Data', component: DataComponent}
])
```

My child LeftNavComponent that looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'left-nav',
  directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ],
  providers: [ ROUTER_PROVIDERS ],
  template: '<a [routerLink]="[ 'Data' ]">Show Me Data</a>'    
})
```

and the DataComponent I'm trying to load in the router-outlet looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'data',
  templateUrl: 'This is where the data will be'
})
```

When I click the link, the url changes to /data, but it seems the DataComponent is not actually loaded because the 'This is where the data will be' text does not appear.

I've verified that the RouteConfig is working properly, since the text appears if I put the router-link in the AppComponent template, so the issue appears to be that the router-link is in the child component.

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
template: '<a [routerLink]="[ '../Data' ]">Show Me Data</a>'
```

or if it is a route on the root component:

```
template: '<a [routerLink]="[ '/Data' ]">Show Me Data</a>'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried both but neither appear to work. /Data navigates to the right URL, but doesn't load the component. ../Data throws this exception: Link "["../Data"]" has too many "../" segments.

Comment: `[ ROUTER_PROVIDERS ],` should only be added in `bootstrap` **or** on the root component `AppComponent` but **never** on any other component.

Comment: There were other issues in your code. `templateUrl` instead of `template` (probably just copy-paste issue). `'` around the template of `left-nav` conflicts with the `'` around `'data'`. I changed the outer to a backtick (probably also just a copy-paste issue). [**Working Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/9ljkpB?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks! I was also missing the location strategy in main.ts. Sorry for the confusion. In my actual code I have the templates in separate files. Tried to stick them in the component to keep the code snippets brief here, and ended up introducing those syntax problems.

Comment: Yup! Thanks a ton. I searched for hours and couldn't find a answer to this.